# How to connect the same database with web application and android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am creating a complaint management system for my university final year project with two components
1-an android app through which the user launches a complaint.
2- web application for admin that can see and take action on complaints launched through the app

PROBLEM : I need to connect both of these application to a single database, how do I go about doing that ?
Should I use API PHPmyadmin ....I seriously do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Neither should connect to the Database. You frontend / client / app should never talk to the DB directly.

You need to create an API in between, that API is hosted on your server and talks to the Database. The clients talk to the API and the API can manage who is allowed to do what, determine if they are authenticated, do some logging, etc.